# Adobe LiveCycle preload XML data from ASP.NET Microsoft SQL

Tags: asp.net, adobe, xfa

I am using Adobe LiveCycle ES2 to create XFA forms to communicate with ASP.NET.

Would like to know when user open the PDF form (via URL), how to get the Request.QueryString parameter and preload data in the PDF form??

> For example, when user access the PDF via URL http://example.com/site/demo.pdf?id=123

Program will get the id "123" and load the XML data from SQL Server and then inject the XML data into PDF form objects. So that when user open the XFA form, the data is loaded inside already.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Adobe LiveCycle ES2 or simply Adobe LiveCycle **Designer** ES2? There are ways for you to communicate with the PDF document itself via FormsBridge if the document is viewed from within a frame but this isn't optimal.

If you are using the full feature Adobe LiveCycle server, you should let the server do the work. Your server can read in the query string parameter, fetch data from the database, manipulate the data, render the PDF, and return it all within the same call. Short of which you will most likely have to use a WSDL Data Connection from within your PDF form to fetch the data, and load it inside the document.